# PHP & MySQL - Echo a List of Strings

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, list

I am kind of stumped on the idea of echoing a list of strings from a mysql server. How would the process go? The format I want it to be is like this:

```
Name 1
Name 2
Name 3
Name 4
```

However each new name is in a new cell, and I don't know how to gather every single name from the mysql server. PHP is a very new language for me so please go easy :)

Answer (score 1):

Query the table and then loop through the resulting array, this example is assuming the column name is "name"

```
$query = “SELECT * FROM table”;
$showresult = mysql_query($query);

while($results_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($showresult))
{
  echo "Name ".$results_array["name"];
}
```

Comment: Is there any way I can get the full list of the array with all the names, instead of having to echo it one by one?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, you could print_r($results_array) inside the while loop that would print everything inside each row. The while loop is necessary because it iterates through each row, otherwise $results_array would only grab the values of the first row. :) This can be kinda confusing at first, please don't hesitate to keep asking questions, thats how people learn

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three extension modules that provide access to a MySQL server: the old [php-mysql](http://docs.php.net/mysql) module, the [MySQL improved module](http://docs.php.net/mysqli) and [PDO with its MySQL driver](http://docs.php.net/pdo). Pete has given you an example of the "old" MySQL module. Let me show you an example using PDO and [(server-side) prepared statements](http://docs.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements):

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'localonly', 'localonly');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
setupTestdata($pdo);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT foo FROM soTest WHERE id<?');
$stmt->execute( array(3) );
while( false!==($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) ) {
  echo $row['foo'], "\n";
}

echo "same statement again, different parameter:\n";
$stmt->execute( array(5) );
while( false!==($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) ) {
  echo $row['foo'], "\n";
}

function setupTestdata($pdo) {
  $pdo->query('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE soTest (id int auto_increment, foo varchar(16), primary key(id))');
  $pdo->query("INSERT INTO soTest (foo) VALUES ('nameA'), ('nameB'), ('nameC'), ('nameD'), ('nameE')");
}
```

prints

```
nameA
nameB
same statement again, different parameter:
nameA
nameB
nameC
nameD
```